# How to restore Google Accounts from a local backup in MIUI 10?

Tags: backup, miui, miui-10

Lately, I reset my Redmi Note 6 Pro and even backed up everything.

Now, my question is that if I restore the local backup file will my multiple G-Mail or Google accounts get restored too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't restore automatically. You have to manually sign in all the accounts even after back